# Как расположить radio кнопки справа от текста?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="form-group">
                 <label class="radio-inline">Укажите пол:</label>
                 <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio"  type="radio">
                  мужской</label>
                 <label class="radio-inline">
                  <input id="inlineradio2" name="sampleinlineradio" type="radio">
                  женский</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: О_О `мужской <input type="radio">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте местами текст с формой ввода, сначала текст, потом `input`. Советую вам оборачивать текст в тег `<p>`, чтобы управление текстом было более понятным.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                 <label class="radio-inline">Укажите пол:</label>
                 <label class="radio-inline">
                  мужской<input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio"  type="radio">
                  </label>
                 <label class="radio-inline">
                  женский<input id="inlineradio2" name="sampleinlineradio" type="radio">
                 </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, поняла свою ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="form-group">
<span class="radio-inline">Укажите пол:</span>
<label class="radio-inline" for="inlineradio1">мужской</label> <!-- обратите внимание на <label></label> -->
<input id="inlineradio1" name="sampleinlineradio"  type="radio">
<label class="radio-inline" for="inlineradio2">женский</label> <!-- обратите внимание на <label></label> -->
<input id="inlineradio2" name="sampleinlineradio" type="radio">
</div>
```

Comment: А для чего обращать внимание?) Радио-кнопки как раз и оставляют внутри label, чтобы они отмечались и при клике на другие области label, нет? Тогда и for-id не нужен...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME аа, этого я не знал. спасибо. оставьте новый ответ